# There are similar old question but It does not answer my question. Should I raise a new question or comment on old question to get the right answer?

Tags: discussion, support

There are similar old questions but they do not answer my question. So people mark as a duplicate when we raise a new question.

What is the best way to get the answer that we expect?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the answers in the duplicate don't answer your question (e.g. they are outdated, just wrong, etc.) you should mention that in your question.

You could add a paragraph for each answer you tried, with what happens when you try it. For example

> I tried [person1's answer](http://#), with this code `code`, but it gives me the following error `Exact error message`

or

> [Person2's answer](http://#) works with most inputs, but with `this input` gives the wrong result

This should normally prevent a new question from being closed as a duplicate of the old one.

Comment: your username is auto generated one or you change it as user000001 ?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson I changed it several years ago